# Variation of vector field under Lorentz transformation and gauge transformation

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, field-theory, poincare-symmetry

In a paper I am reading, it is stated that under a Lorentz transformation, the coordinates transform as $x^{\mu} \to \Lambda^{\mu}_{\nu}x^{\nu}$, and so the change in the (vector) field at the same value of the co-ordinate is $\delta A^{\mu}=\omega^{\mu}_{\nu}A^{\nu}+\partial^{\mu}\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is a gauge transformation, which we use to preserve the gauge choice.

When I try to find the variation, I am getting $\delta A^{\mu}=\omega^{\mu}_{\nu}A^{\nu}(x)-\omega^{\nu}_ix^i\partial_{\nu}{A'}^{\mu}(x)$. Now I understand that in order to preserve the gauge choice, we would have to include an extra parameter $\partial^{\mu}\alpha$, however I can't seem to get rid of the extra term $-\omega^{\nu}_ix^i\partial_{\nu}{A'}^{\mu}(x)$. A similar question was also asked on this website [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/154173/lorentz-transformation-bjorken-drell?rq=1), but it is also unanswered.

Comment: What paper are you talking about?

Comment: Can you write out the lagrangian your are transforming? that makes all the difference

Comment: Where does $\alpha$ come from? Why consider gauge and Lorentz transformation at the same time?

Comment: @my2cts If we are working in a gauge, say Light cone gauge, then after a lorentz transformation, to remain in the gauge, the field should transform like that.

Comment: @InertialObserver we are just looking at the transformation of the four vector field; there is no Lagrangian.

Comment: @Chetan Pandey A gauge that breaks even Lorentz covariance. Nothing is sacred in gauge theory.

Comment: @my2cts LC gauge breaks manifest Lorentz covariance; the theory is still covariant, which can be checked by looking at the closure of the Poincare algebra; which is roughly what I was doing.

Comment: @ChetanPandey can you link the paper?

Comment: @ChetanPandey I just went through the calculations and I get your result (except for the fact that I get an umprimed $A$ in the right-hand side). But I was expect that, because that is the part that takes into account the transformation of the 4-vector field as a function of spacetime (indeed, it's the same part that appears when transforming a scalar field).

Comment: @Luthien I redid the calculation and I am getting the unprimed $A$ too, in the right hand side; and I think that now my query is resolved; I believe that in the paper, they were looking for the spin generators only, due to which they were not taking the orbital part into account. Anyways, thanks for your help!